# How to import csv file into mongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i'm new to Python.
I want to insert specific columns of a csv file into a collection in my mongodb, i know how to do it with the shell but i want to do it with python, as i'm learning Python.

This is what i have so far:

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
import sys, getopt, pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
#CSV to JSON Conversion
with open('netflix_titles.csv','rt', encoding="utf8") as file:
data = file.read()
mongo_client=MongoClient() 
db=mongo_client.Netflix
db.segment.drop()
header= [ "show_id", "director"]

for each in data:
    row={}
    for field in header:
        row[field]=each[field]  

    db.segment.insert(row)
```

In only throws me an indented error in this line:

```
data = file.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the `csv` module then definitely use the reader function of that module.  It will deal with quotes, whitespace, etc. etc.   Also, not sure if your

```
for each in data:
```

Is actually doing the CSV breakup you think it is.  This is more tidy (assuming you want to drive the action from a static array of header names):

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    header = [ "show_id", "director"]
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        doc={}
        for n in range(0,len(header)):
            doc[header[n]] = row[n]

        db.foo.insert(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put tab before `date = file.read()` , because `with` increase indentation level.